# Why does my C# .net 8 program, with an await operator, using a task, tell me that I do not have a await operator?

Tags: c#, async-await, task

This code is trying to get details of a Complex Type Value.

I am using a task with await.  However, I still get a warning that the await operator does
not exist.

I am not sure where I have gone wrong with the syntax or my understanding.

```
namespace TaskWithReturnComplexTypeValue
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SomeMethod();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private async static void SomeMethod()
        {
            Employee emp = await GetEmployeeDetails();
            Console.WriteLine($"Id:{emp.Id}, Name: {emp.Name}, Salary: {emp.Salary} ");
        }

        // I get a warning about this async  method not having an await operator, though I am   using one above.
        static async Task<Employee> GetEmployeeDetails()
        {
            Employee employee = new Employee()
            {
                Id = 101,
                Name = "Kiran Kumar",
                Salary = 1000
            };
            return employee;
        }

        public class Employee
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
            public int Salary { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting this program to run .  However I get a warning that says" This async method does not have an await operator.

Comment: Don't forget that when `GetEmployeeDetails()` returns an incomplete task, the `Console.ReadKey();` will be called before the task is completed.

Comment: `private async static void SomeMethod()` should be `private async static Task SomeMethod()` and `static void Main(string[] args) { SomeMethod();` should be `static async Task Main(string[] args) { await SomeMethod();`

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable advice.  I need to gain more knowledge about this subject.  Your comments pointed me in the right directions.

Answer (score 3):

You don't *need* to use the `async` keyword to make an asynchronous method. (At least if you're using TPL, which is more-or-less the defacto standard), all that matters is that you return a `Task` or `Task<...>`. The `async` keyword is *optional*, and just adds some syntax sugar behind the scenes to allow you to return the `<...>` object directly without needing to wrap it in a Task object, and allows you to use `await`.

You can remove the `async` keyword from your method like this (note the return line)

```
static Task<Employee> GetEmployeeDetails()
{
    Employee employee = new Employee()
    {
        Id = 101,
        Name = "Kiran Kumar",
        Salary = 1000
    };
    return Task.FromResult(employee);
}
```

It's important to know that whether the `GetEmployeeDetails` method itself uses `async` or not is *entirely independent* from the method that calls it. `SomeMethod` has `async` and `await`, but that has no bearing on how `GetEmployeeDetails` works.

---

Now, as your `GetEmployeeDetails` method currently stands, there is no reason to make it asynchronous. You simply make an object in memory and return it. Asynchronous methods are best for operations that are not CPU-bound, such as IO, network, database, HTTP, etc. If you're planning on adding code later to justify asynchronous use, great, but as it currently is, I'd recommend *not* having it asynchronous.

Comment: I am trying to learn how to use Async with tasks.  Hence I started with a simple example.

Comment: I would not say the `async` keyword was "optional". If your method needs one or more `await` expressions in its body, then the `async` keyword is mandatory. And the C# compiler will automatically rewrite the portion of your method that comes after `await` into a _continuation_. So it is not just that you can `return` an expression of type `Employee` and have it converted to a `Task<Employee>`; the entire method becomes magical if there is just one `await`. But if there is no `await`, there is no magic, and the `async` keyword is misleading, hence the warning.

Comment: (continued) But your answer illuminates beautifully that a method can be _awaitable_, for returning a `Task<>` or similar type that supports getting an awaiter, without having any `await` itself. So it makes sense to have the signature `static Task<Employee> GetEmployeeDetailsAsync()` without `async` keyword, but with a name ending in -Async to signal to the caller that the return type is awaitable.